# What does auth signify in firebase rules?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to imply rules in firebase that every logged in user can read any data on web app. When I log in user through api, i am mot able to read any information through my database. I am using pyrbase library.
Here is my code:

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(configS)
auth=firebase.auth()
db=firebase.database()
email="varun@firebase.com"
password="varun1"

def createUser(data):
    user=auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("admin@firebase.com","admin1")
    # user=auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email,password) 
    return db.child("users").child(user['localId']).set(data)

def loginUser():
    return auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,password)

def readData(branch):
    user=loginUser(email,password)
    return db.child(branch).get().val()

def writeData(branch,data):
    user=loginUser(email,password)
    return db.child(branch).push(data,user['idToken'])

results = createUser(dict(name="varun",phone="8787878787"))

# results=readData("responses")

# results=writeData("responses",dict(question="what?",answer="yes"))

print(results)
```

Here are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":"auth!=null",
    "responses":{
      ".write":"auth!=null"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my database structure:

```
{
  "admin":{
    "name": ()
    "id": ()
  }
  "users":{
    "user_id":
  }
  "responses":{

  }
  "surveys":{

  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error message or unexpected behavior you're experiencing, and explain how your title relates to the question.

Comment: I have solved this problem. My user was getting authenticated. I was not using token. I have included it now. Thanks.